# Assign Name of TWinControl component to Caption property

Tags: delphi, components, vcl

I'm trying to create a custom label based on TWinControl.
I'm using TWinControl because on the control there will be 2 labels and one shape.

Now, for simplicity reasons, in this example from below, I would like to populate the Caption property of this TWinControl with the name of component.

Because the Name of the component is not available during creation, I need to find another way.

```
unit MappLabelTest;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Themes, Vcl.ComCtrls,
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils, System.Types;

type
  [ComponentPlatformsAttribute(pidWin32 or pidWin64)]
  TMappLabelTest = class(TWinControl)
  private
    FCaption: TCaption;
    procedure SetCaption(const AValue: TCaption);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Caption: TCaption read FCaption write SetCaption;
  end;

implementation

constructor TMappLabelTest.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  ParentBackground:= True;

  Width:= 121;
  Height:= 21;

  FCaption:= Name; // Name is blank here...
end;

destructor TMappLabelTest.Destroy;
begin

  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TMappLabelTest.SetCaption(const AValue: TCaption);
begin
  FCaption:= AValue;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Does removin `csSetCaption` from `ControlStyle` do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

Override your Component's SetName method.  Look at TControl.SetName for an example as to when or when not to set your Caption property.

Comment: I need to set the Caption as Name, only before the values are read from dfm, otherwise Caption should take it's normal value set by programmer

Comment: The value of Name is empty until SetName is called.  You need to look at the state of your component as TControl.SetName does to determine whether not you should set the Caption property

Comment: If I did it correctly, looks that SetName does not triggered when component is dropped on form.

Comment: Solved with CreateWnd procedure

Answer (score 0):

Result can be achieved by using `CreateWnd` procedure. This procedure is invoked before loading design values.

```
unit MappLabelTest;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Themes, Vcl.ComCtrls, System.Classes, System.SysUtils, System.Types;

type
  [ComponentPlatformsAttribute(pidWin32 or pidWin64)]
  TMappLabelTest = class(TWinControl)
  private
    FCaption: TCaption;
    procedure SetCaption(const AValue: TCaption);
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Caption: TCaption read FCaption write SetCaption;
  end;

implementation

constructor TMappLabelTest.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  ParentBackground:= True;

  Width:= 121;
  Height:= 21;

  FCaption:= '';
end;

destructor TMappLabelTest.Destroy;
begin

  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TMappLabelTest.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  FCaption:= Name;
end;

procedure TMappLabelTest.SetCaption(const AValue: TCaption);
begin
  FCaption:= AValue;
end;

end.
```